# Solving for $\theta$ in $\left(a^2+b^2+\left(b^2-a^2\right)\cos 2\theta\right )(1-\cos\left (2\theta-c\right )) = d$

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to solve this equation for the variable $\theta$?

$$\left (a^{2}+b^{2}+\left (b^{2}-a^{2} \right ) \cos\left (2\theta  \right )\right ) \left (1-\cos\left (2\theta-c\right )\right ) = d$$

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Maybe. Use the difference of angles formula on $\cos\left (2\theta-c\right )$, which will express it as a combination of $\cos\left (2\theta  \right)$ and $\sin\left (2\theta  \right)$. Make a substitution $t:=\cos\left (2\theta  \right)$, then $\sin\left (2\theta  \right)=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. Solve for the latter and square both sides. You'll get a polynomial equation for $t$, it will be very messy, probably of order $4$. If you get lucky it factors.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your equation in the form
$$(a^2+b^2+(b^2-a^2)\cos(2\theta))(1-\cos(2\theta)\cos(c)-\sin(2\theta)\sin(c))=d$$
Now substitute $$A=\sin(2\theta),B=\cos(2\theta)$$ and using $$A^2+B ^2=1$$ you will get two equations to solve for $\theta$.
Can you go on or should i send you the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you start expanding $\cos(2\theta-c)$ and use the tangent half-angle subsitution $x=\tan(\theta)$, you will end with a quartic polynomial in $x$
$$\alpha x^4+\beta x^3+\gamma x^2+\delta x+ \epsilon=0$$ where
$$\alpha=2 a^2 \cos (c)+2 a^2-d$$
$$\beta=-4 a^2 \sin (c)$$
$$\gamma=2 \left(\left(b^2-a^2\right) \cos (c)+a^2+b^2-d\right)$$
$$\delta=-4 b^2 \sin (c)$$
$$\epsilon=-2 b^2 \cos (c)+2 b^2-d$$